# When does jQuery Mobile enhance page content?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have run into a small issue with jQuery Mobile enhancing collapsibles and flip switches twice over - the end result being that I see "double".  I am still trying to pin down the problem but there are some peculiar things I need to do to get my application to work

- jQuery, jQM and the relevant CSS are being fetched from a CDN
- I do some extra work in $(document).ready which is placed at the foot of the document, after the closing body tag.

My original markup that is along the lines of

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
<h3>Hello World</h3>
<p>How are you</p>
</div>
```

gets "enhanced" to

```
<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
<a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit">
<a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit">
Hello World
```

click to collapse contents
    click to collapse contents

instead of

```
<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
<a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-left 
 ui-btn-inherit">
Hello World
<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span>
</a></h3>
```

as it would normally be.  It seems to me that with the ordering of my CSS, JS and $(document).ready I am inadvertently causing jQM to do a selective double enhancement on accordions, collapsibles and flip switches (listviews etc appear to go unscathed).

I'd much appreciate if anyone might be able to tell me just when and where jQM performs its enahncement operations so i can pin down the problem

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem, or at least show us the script in your ready() function?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - if you run into something similar you almost certainly have two references to jQM.  In my case I had one reference generated from a *required* file that I had not touched in ages and then in a recent edit I put in one more in my page markup generation code.  BOOM!